# How find non repeating item in array Golang

Tags: arrays, go

I have an input integer array which has only one non duplicate number, like {1,1,3,2,3}. The output should show the non duplicate element i.e. 2.

```
func main() {
    arr := make([]string, 0)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for {
        scanner.Scan()
        text := scanner.Text()
        if len(text) != 0 {
            arr = append(arr, text)
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
    uniq := Unique(arr)
    fmt.Println(uniq)
}

func Unique(arr []string) int {
    var uni int
    for i := 0; i < len(arr); i++ {
        for j := i + 1; j < len(arr); j++ {
            if(arr[i] != arr[j]){
                uni = i
            }
        }
    }
    return uni
}
```

Comment: You have to check all number in the inner loop then decides is `arr[i]` is unique or not. You can use a bool flag for that. Have a look https://play.golang.org/p/E-APdhm8sZL

Comment: you can increment a `map[int]int` each time an integer is present in your original array. Then iterate over map and return the element(s) which are only occurring once, that is complexity n^2. However if there is only one unique element, you could store it in a `var temp int` and keep replacing this when you find multiple copies. That will be O(n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1., It's more like a mathematical problem.
2., You always should count all the unique integers present in your array as @whitespace mentioned. But it's more like `O(2n)` and not `O(n^2)`. You should iterate over your original array and then the map which length will be <= n (in the worst case you have `n` unique item in your array).
I created a go-playground example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/NLBAXWB0JGM).